# not displaying several html blocks if condition not met in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to restrict the information being shown if data in not available.

In my view.rb file, I have something like this

```
<% if @content != nil %>
 <div>
   <h3>....</h3>
    <% @content[0..3].each do |something| %>  
     <li> .... <li>
    <% end %>
    <% @content[4..5].each do |something| %>  
     <li> .... <li>
    <% end %>
    <% @content[5..11].each do |something| %>  
     <li> .... <li>
    <% end %>
 <div>
<% end %>
```

how ever even if content is nil, lines like content[4..5].each do |something| is being run and throwing errors for obvious reasons.

How do I get multiple blocks of html and ruby code to be ignored if condition isn't being met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code `<% content[4..5].each do |something| %>` is executed, then *@content* IS NOT nil, there is no way ruby could be wrong about that.

BUT, if it is something like an empty array or a blank string then it will pass the test. In order to cover a wide range of possible "nil-like" values (nil, empty, blank...) use:

```
<% unless @content.blank? %>
```

And let me know if it helps.

Comment: hmm I was getting the error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" so I assumed it was a nil

Comment: Are you sure you meant `content[4..5].each` and not `@content[4..5].each`? Or vice versa maybe?

Comment: it worked with unless, but im still confused as to why nil wasn't caught

Comment: Don't know either... sorry about that : )

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
 <% unless @content.nil? %>
      #true
 <%else%>
      #false
 <%end%>
```

Comment: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2699-making-sense-with-rubys-unless, bullet point 3 "Never, ever, ever use an else clause with an unless statement."

Comment: If that's the case, we can use `<% if @content.nil? %>` condition

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure @content is surely nil? Please be aware that an object can be empty while it is not nil.

Eg:

@content=[]

or

@content={}

will make hold true for @content!=nil since it is not actually not nil. A reference is nil if it is never instantiated before.

If you are storing data to @content via a database query like Modelname,All , then you will get an empty array instead of a null (nil) object.

Also, if you are recieving @content from user as request parameter, then if the GET request contains name of the parameter but not any value, then again @content is empty but not nil.

ie http://yourdomain.com/somecontroller/index?name=10&age=
will have params[:age] as empty nil.

Solution:

```
<% if @content.to_s.empty? != true %>
<div>
<h3>....</h3>
<% content[0..3].each do |something| %>  
 <li> .... <li>
<% end %>
<% content[4..5].each do |something| %>  
 <li> .... <li>
<% end %>
<% content[5..11].each do |something| %>  
 <li> .... <li>
<% end %>
<div>
<% end %>
```